# Yii2 pretty url for action with parameters

Tags: yii2, friendly-url

please, help me with the pattern for such url `http://electric/search?art=dddd`

I need it to look like: `http://electric/search/art/dddd`

Answer (score 1):

If electric is your controller and search is the action then you can use something like this:

```
'urlManager' => [
    ...
    'rules' => [
        ...
        'search/art/<art:[a-zA-Z]+>' => 'site/search',
        ...
    ],
    ...
],
```

You might want to modify the part with the regular expression so you can define exactly what characters you want `art` to accept.

Comment: I have hidden  the default `site` controller, and edited the rule as follows: `'search/art/<art:[a-zA-Z]+>' => 'site/search'`, however, this rule did not help. I have already tried many rules, but nothing helps. I have other rules on my site, and they work, except this.

Comment: `electric` - is a domain name

Comment: You should check the order in which the rules are declared, the first rule that matches is the one that gets used, so you need to make sure the most specific cases are declared before the more general ones.